# SQL Query - Using CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, subquery

For the following data:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nwotc7j2p5mn63a/Sample.odt?dl=0

I need to retrieve shortname as the sum in columns and not rows. How can I do that using CASE?

Thank you.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am sorry. I am not able to paste the table here. I am using SQL Server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, write data in proper columns, highlight and click `{}`.

Comment: I hope this document helps : https://www.dropbox.com/s/nwotc7j2p5mn63a/Sample.odt?dl=0

Comment: I'm sorry, but very few people will download a document. Make it easy to assist you, write a self-contained question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build each column using its own select statement.  Like so.  Try it out.

```
(select sum(amount) from CurrentData where shortname='Loans') as LoanSum, (select sum(amount) from CurrentData where shortname='W-2') as W-2Sum
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Avi, if this resolved your issue, can you please mark my answer as accepted?  Thanks so much. :)